# Regex Condition

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, validation

I tried to get the following conditions into a regex:

-The first condition is user can't insert number " 0 " in first digit , when user input " 0 " , error message "wrong format" will shown

-Second condition is user only can input 9 digit and just numeric.when user input number less 9 , error message " input 9 digits number" will shown.

this is my current code :

```
<form ng-submit="okPhoneAction(phonePopUp, prompt.phoneNumber)" name="phonePopUp" novalidate>
    <div class="popupBodyNav">
        <p>Please enter your phone number</p>
         <label class="item item-input down" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 80%; margin-left: 10%;">
             <i class="placeholder-icon" style="font-size: 14px;">+971</i>
         <input ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" ng-minlength="9" maxlength="9" ng-model="prompt.phoneNumber" ng-pattern="/^\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,15})?$/" required/>

         </label>
         <div class="error-container text-left" ng-show="phonePopUp.phoneNumber.$invalid && phonePopUp.phoneNumber.$dirty">
             <p ng-if="phonePopUp.phoneNumber.$error.required " class="help-block validatext-pop" style="font-size: 12px" translate="VALIDATION.required">Phone number can not be empty</p>
            <p ng-if="phonePopUp.phoneNumber.$error.minlength" class="help-block validatext-pop" style="font-size: 12px" translate="VALIDATION.mobileNumber">input 9 digits number</p>
            <p ng-if="phonePopUp.phoneNumber.$error.pattern" class="help-block validatext-pop" style="font-size: 12px; color: #fff !important;" translate="VALIDATION.antiZero">wrong format</p>
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="popupBottomNav">
        <div class="halfBottomNav">
            <input type="submit" class="buttonWhite" value="Cancel" ng-click="closePromtPhone()" />
        </div>
        <div class="halfBottomNav">
            <input type="submit" class="buttonWhite" value="OK" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

can you help me to fix the code ?
- thanks

Comment: As @Tushar says, but add ^ and $  /^[1-9][0-9]{8}$ / to reject strings like asd999999999

Comment: Okay thanks guys,
and know how to make condition so if user input "0" will call error message " wrong format" will shown , but if user input number less than 9 error message will call error message " input 9 digits " ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting up to check a standard 10 digit phone number configuration, then give this a try.

```
"/^[1-9]{1}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/"
```